# Paradox instantiation

Tags: java

Any thoughts to instantiate Paradox class without modifying the class itself?

```
public final class Paradox {
    private final Paradox paradox;

    public Paradox(Paradox paradox) {
        this.paradox = paradox;
        if (this.paradox == null) throw new InceptionException();
    }

    private static class InceptionException extends RuntimeException {
        public InceptionException() {
            super("Paradox requires an instance of paradox to be instantiated");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible without using reflection or `sun.misc.Unsafe`.

Comment: Even with reflection I'm not sure you can do it

Comment: is mocking a solution? https://objectpartners.com/2012/03/15/how-to-mock-final-classes-in-unit-tests/

Comment: This is more code golf but still interesting nonetheless!

Comment: Debug breakpoint in the constructor and set next statement somewhere else ought to do it. Debugging code you know is a well-defined operation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments: It is possible with the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;

public class ParadoxTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Constructor<Unsafe> unsafeConstructor = 
            Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        unsafeConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = unsafeConstructor.newInstance();
        Paradox paradox = (Paradox) unsafe.allocateInstance(Paradox.class);
        System.out.println("This is paradox: "+paradox);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, one could use the [JNI function `AllocObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#AllocObject), which also allocates a new object without invoking any of the constructors.

> EDIT: [Someone found another solution](http://forum.byte-welt.net/java-forum-das-java-welt-kompetenz-zentrum-wir-wissen-und-helfen-/allgemeine-themen/4929-java-quiz-16.html#post122512) - without `sun.misc.Unsafe`!
>
> EDIT2: But note that this solution also uses Sun proprietary classes, which are **not** part of the public API, and so this solution is still **not portable** and should **not** be used in production code!

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory;

public class AnotherParadoxTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ReflectionFactory rf = ReflectionFactory.getReflectionFactory();
        Constructor<?> declaredConstructor = 
            Object.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        Constructor<?> constructor = rf.newConstructorForSerialization(
            Paradox.class, declaredConstructor);
        Paradox paradox = (Paradox) constructor.newInstance();
        System.out.println("This is paradox: "+paradox);
    }
    
}
```

> EDIT3: Just for completeness, and per request in the comments: The JNI-based solution

As mentioned above, the [JNI function `AllocObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#AllocObject) does not call a constructor, so this may also be used to instantiate such an object. This is the calling class which contains the native method and loads the native library:

```
public class ParadoxTestWithJni
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("Paradox");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Paradox paradox = createParadox();
        System.out.println("This is paradox: "+paradox);
    }

    private native static Paradox createParadox();
}
```

The header `ParadoxTestWithJni.h` that was created for this class with `javah`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#ifndef _Included_ParadoxTestWithJni
#define _Included_ParadoxTestWithJni
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_ParadoxTestWithJni_createParadox
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The corresponding implementation ... "where the magic happens":

```
#include "ParadoxTestWithJni.h"
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_ParadoxTestWithJni_createParadox
(JNIEnv *env, jclass c)
{
    jclass paradoxClass = env->FindClass("Paradox");
    jobject paradox = env->AllocObject(paradoxClass);
    return paradox;
}
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering **IF YOU WRITE THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE, DAEMONS WILL TEAR OFF YOUR HANDS**

Comment: @christopher And it will magically stop running with Java 9. But the daemon thread choppy thing is scary, too.

Comment: @christopher ... yes, and everytime you write this, god kills a unicorn. But seriously, I think this question was rather intended as a puzzle...

Comment: Are there other ways (reflection was mentioned) to do this? A JNI example would also be nice. Are there any real world use cases for this?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not sure whether a JNI example would bring many insights (basically a single method which calls AllocObject and returns the result, plus the typical (veeery verbose) JNI boilerplate code), but I'll consider adding one, just for completeness. Do the "use cases" refer to this Paradox example, or JNI instantiation in general?

Answer (score 13):

Let's say that the `Paradox` class is in a package `test`, like this (of course it could be in the default package, but the question doesn't really specify it):

```
package test;

public final class Paradox {
    private final Paradox paradox;

    public Paradox(Paradox paradox) {
        this.paradox = paradox;
        if (this.paradox == null) throw new InceptionException();
    }

    private static class InceptionException extends RuntimeException {
        public InceptionException() {
            super("Paradox requires an instance of paradox to be instantiated");
        }
    }
}
```

An XML representation, if it had been serialized by [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/), of the class would look like this:

```xml
<test.Paradox/>
```

Given this XML, it can be deserialized without calling the constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    Paradox paradoxFromXml = (Paradox) xstream.fromXML("<test.Paradox/>");
    System.out.println(paradoxFromXml);
}
```

The output is:

> test.Paradox@72d818d1

This answer takes advantage of the fact that XStream doesn't call a constructor during deserialization, as stated in their [FAQ](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html):

> **XStream is not calling the default constructor during deserialization.**
>   This is, in fact, the same case as above. XStream uses the same mechanism as the JDK serialization. When using the enhanced mode with the optimized reflection API, it does not invoke the default constructor. The solution is to implement the readResolve or readObject as demonstrated with the last question.

So, by utilizing the straightforward XML representation XStream has by default, the class can be initialized through deserialization, despite the fact that the class is not serializable.

As a further explanation to this, XStream in this case probably initializes the class by using  [`SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider`](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/blob/master/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/reflection/SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider.java) or [`SunUnsafeReflectionProvider`](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/blob/master/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/reflection/SunUnsafeReflectionProvider.java), which internally uses `sun.misc.Unsafe`, as their Javadoc states (thanks to [marco13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182664/marco13) for pointing this out):

**`SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider`:**

```
/**
 * Instantiates a new object bypassing the constructor using undocumented internal JDK features.
 * <p>
 * The code in the constructor will never be executed and parameters do not have to be known. This is the same method
 * used by the internals of standard Java serialization, but relies on internal code (sun.misc.Unsafe) that may not be
 * present on all JVMs.
 * <p>
 * <p>
 * The implementation will use standard Java functionality to write any fields. This requires Java 5 as minimum runtime
 * and is used as fallback on platforms that do not provide the complete implementation level for the internals (like
 * Dalvik).
 * <p>
 * 
 * @author J&ouml;rg Schaible
 * @author Joe Walnes
 * @author Brian Slesinsky
 * @since 1.4.7
 */
```

**`SunUnsafeReflectionProvider`**:

```
/**
 * Instantiates a new object bypassing the constructor using undocumented internal JDK features.
 * <p>
 * The code in the constructor will never be executed and parameters do not have to be known. This is the same method
 * used by the internals of standard Java serialization, but relies on internal code (sun.misc.Unsafe) that may not be
 * present on all JVMs.
 * <p>
 * <p>
 * The implementation will use the same internals to write into fields. This is a lot faster and was additionally the
 * only possibility to set final fields prior to Java 5.
 * <p>
 *
 * @author Joe Walnes
 * @author Brian Slesinsky
 * @author J&ouml;rg Schaible
 * @since 1.4.7
 */
```

In all honesty, I just remembered that XStream had the capabilities to initialize objects without calling constructors, without having the time at the moment of answering the question to dig further into it.

Comment: I think people are more interested in how it works than seeing some magic library do the right thing

Comment: @Dici Fair enough. I added a small explanation to my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum But also allows you to deserialize the object from a few characters of XML.

Comment: @Magnilex right, but I might as well create a library that does `createFromClass("Paradox")` and use _that_ instead, even shorter - still does not describe what really happens inside.

Comment: How does XStream create an object without calling any constructors? As far as I know that can't be done via java.lang.reflect. This answer raises a question that it does not answer.